# Cannot get Browser Sync to detect changes

Tags: command-line, browser-sync

I'm having some issues with Browser Sync on a local Wordpress project. When I run:

```
browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8888 --files "*"
```

I get the following:

```
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:8888
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
Local: http://localhost:3000
External: http://192.168.1.84:3000
UI: http://localhost:3001  
UI External: http://localhost:3001 
[Browsersync] Watching files...
```

But then no changes are detected. It's my first time using BS so I'm sure it's an easy fix, I just don't know what that fix is. Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using a different command:

```
browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:8888' --watch  --files "**/*"
```

It didn't work at first, but I went off and worked on something else for a while and when I came back it was working. No idea what could be the cause of that but it's working anyway/